# 404 returning to site index

Tags: 404

I just realized that when I go to website.com/faljalsdfkj, it should cause a 404 and take me to the 404 page. I have this same setup on ann older site and it seems to be working correctly, but Can't figure out what's different. I don't have strict urls turned on because I need this setting for a feature.

After viewing this thread:

[404 ErrorDocument returns home page incorrectly](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/20242/404-errordocument-returns-home-page-incorrectly)

it seems that perhaps its my apache configuration? Or is there another setting im missing?

Any ideas would be huge. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading the home page in 404 mode is EE's default functionality. Unless you configure/code otherwise this is just what happens.

Can't you add this to your home page template?

```
{if segment_1 !=""}
  {redirect="404"}
{/if}
```

This assumes you have a template specified as your 404 template in the area of the CP that Alex provided a screenshot of.

Comment: Nice-This should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you have enabled "Strict URLs" and chosen you 404 template in in the control panel.

> **Control Panel Location:** Design > Templates > Template Preferences

[image]

Take a look at [Global Template Preferences](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/global_template_preferences.html) in the ExpressionEngine User Guide for more information.

Comment: I can't enable strict URLS because at this time I am using segments for returning on errors and success form submissions. If it was contact/success then it would trigger a 404. I have an older EE site - 2.5 that works (without strict urls). So im trying to figure out why it is the index that is treated as the 404.